# Prevent Duplicate Entry in Data table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am using data table to store the Employee details. I need to prevent the duplicate entry.

**Code behind:**

```
try
{
    strServerSelectedName = txtServerName.Text;    
    string dCurrentDateTIme = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());    
    DataTable ds1 = new DataTable();    
    DataRow dr1 = ds1.NewRow();    
    iServerSelectedid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["SelectedServerId"].ToString());    
    ds1 = datalayer.getServiceDetails(iServerSelectedid);     
    ds1.Columns["servicename"].Unique = true;   
    string strServiceName = txtServiceName.Text;    
    string strDescription = txtareaDescription.Text;    
    string UserName = usernameshown.Text;    
    datalayer.insertsingleservice(iServerSelectedid, UserName, dCurrentDateTIme, strServiceName, strDescription);    
    ds1 = datalayer.getServiceDetails(iServerSelectedid); 
    grdServerDetails.DataSource = ds1;
    grdServerDetails.DataBind();    
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Alert.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am using unique key to prevent duplicate values in code behind but i won't help me to recover the issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Actually this "ds1.Columns["servicename"].Unique = true;" is not handle the duplicate values @toddlermenit.

Comment: Why don't use DISTINCT in your sql query before put datas in your table ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [PrimaryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx) in your datatable or [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No @Fabio I have one server table and details table. the details table contains many details for particular server. I have to restrict the duplicate details values for particular server.

Comment: Add a [unique constrain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.uniqueconstraint(v=vs.110).aspx) on the pair id server, id detail in the table details

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique constraint you will need to declare it like this:

```
 UniqueConstraint cnst = 
   new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] {ds1.Columns["servicename"]});
ds1.Constraints.Add(cnst);
```